# Is there a way to make a program only usable by a windows administrator?

Tags: windows, user

I want to install a program however I do not want anyone else to be able to use it?  Is there a way to limit it to only the administrator on windows 10?

Comment: Perhaps just [change the permissions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/what-are-permissions#1TC=windows-7) on the program's EXE?

Comment: Ok I got it to work.  apparently I am a "User" with admin priv.  I thought that made me an admin in the permissions.  So I disabled inheritance deleted all users and just added myself back.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the permissions on the directory for the program so that it denies all permissions to the users group.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Well I did that but apparently I locked the administrator out too!  Is there any way to give it back?

Comment: Deny rules always beat Allow rules. If you Deny everyone, then everyone is denied, regardless of any other rules.

Comment: It tells me I need to turn off inheritance.  Should I do that and if I do what are the implications>?

Comment: Because the Admin is a part of the user group so it denied even the admin.

Comment: I'd have added everyone else to another group first, then locked out that group... rather than myself too ;)